# Using aws-cli in cronjob

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm trying to run `aws sts get-caller-identity` in a cronjob, however this results in `/bin/sh: 1: aws: not found`

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: Apparently, aws is not in the path? Have you checked if aws-cli is part of the container image? Have you tried to address the aws binary directly? For me this would be /usr/local/bin/aws.

Comment: Can you update you question with your image specs? That would make the issue to found much easier.

Comment: try to use "amazon/aws-cli" Docker image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, it seems that the AWS CLI is not installed in the image that your are using for this cronjob. You need to provide more information!

If you are the owner of the used image, just install the AWS CLI within the Dockerfile. If you are not the owner, just create your own image, extend it from the image you are currently using and install the AWS CLI.

For example, if you are using an Alpine based image, just create a Dockerfile

```
FROM <THE_ORIGINAL_IMAGE>:<TAG>

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip && \
  pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
  pip3 install awscli
```

Then build the image and push it to DockerHub for an example.
Now you can use this new image in your CronJob resource.

BUT, the next thing is that your CronJob Pod needs access to execute the AWS STS service. There are multiple possibilities to get this done. The best way is to use IRSA (IAM Roles for Service Accounts) Just check this blog article https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/

If you still need help, just provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

You need add secrets key to kubernetes secrets:

```
kubectl create secret generic aws-credd --from-literal=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxx --from-literal=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxx
```

Step 2: copy this to -> cronjob.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: aws-cli-sync
  labels:
    app: aws-cli-sync
spec:
  schedule: "0 17 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: aws-cli-sync
            image: mikesir87/aws-cli
            env:
              - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: aws-cred
                    key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: aws-cred
                    key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            args:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - date;aws s3 sync s3://xxx-backup-prod s3://elk-xxx-backup
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Step 3: add job in namespaces there you add key

```
kubectl apply -f ./cronjob.yaml
```